# IPod touch connect to new PC: no file deletion

Tags: data-synchronization, ipod-touch

Is there a way I can plug my Apple device to a different PC to load new content without having the old ones removed?

Comment: What do you mean with "new content" and "old ones"? This question is pretty vague. Could you please improve your question in order to get it clear what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: New content pertains to exactly that. I want to add new songs to my I Touch but it was originally synced to my old laptop which is now in demise. So this time I have to use a different computer to load new songs but I fear for the original contents of my iTouch. I think the answer adequately addressed my question.thank you.follow up: what third party app did you use?

Comment: What generation iPod are you talking about?

Comment: 4th generation iPod touch

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. This is a "Feature" of how iTunes works.

I had to do something like this recently with my wife's old iPod.

The work-around was to use a 3rd-party tool to back up the contents of the iPod before connecting it to the new iTunes. The iPod was wiped and then I copied back in the content.

A pain!

Comment: Depends, with the newest iTunes and iOS 7 you can sync via multiple computers without having your content removed.

Comment: What third party app did you use? And thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, it's on another PC at home. Try this [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=itunes+alternative) which should turn up all the likely tools. If you let me know which ones you try, I'll update the answer.